# Prove that limit of the fractional part of $\sqrt{n^2+n}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, fractional-part

Prove that $$\operatorname{frac}(\sqrt{n^2 + n}) \to \frac{1}{2}$$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\operatorname{frac}$ is fractional part of number)

I think I should use just definition of limit and find $N$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Please show your efforts in solving the problem.

Comment: I am confused. Are you taking the limit as $n$ tends to some value? If so, what value?

Comment: Your problem makes no sense.  Is the limit for $n \to \infty$?  or $n \to 0$?

Comment: What is the frac( - ) function?

Comment: Since we are talking natural numbers, I think the only sensible question to ask would be the limit for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Bib-lost I think real is fine.

Comment: It is sequence and $n \to \infty$ of course.

Comment: Since we are working with the natural numbers we could break this into two square roots... How would you define $\operatorname{frac}(\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: @djechlin Fractional part of $x$ is defined as $x$ minus the integer part of $x$.

Comment: @N.S. frac(e) ~= 0.718 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \geq n^2+n  \geq \left(n+\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{n}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Consider that

$$
\left(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n\right) = (n^2+n)-n^2 = n
$$

Note that $2n < \sqrt{n^2+n}+n < 2n+1$ and squeeze.